# rs.next() returns the same row 3 times on using h2 db

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I am using embedded H2 db. `rs.next()` returns the every row 3 times.
Here is my code.

```
    try {
        query = "select * from invoice_count;";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + String.valueOf(rs.getInt(2)));
        }   
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The result is

```
    17fb 1
    17jn 45
    17fb 1
    17jn 45
    17fb 1
    17jn 45
```

Actual data in db :

[image: Actual data in db :]

why rs.next() again goes to first row?

Comment: Well, then your database contains those rows 3 times... or your code is executed three times in a row. Note that your "actual data in db" proves nothing: it might be a different database, and in any case it would also be executed through JDBC, and should therefor produce equivalent results. Nothing in your code seems to be wrong, so either your assumption about the data is wrong, or you need to show a lot more context.

Comment: Yes.my code is executed 3 times.But why?

Comment: Then don't execute it three times.

Comment: Is the try/catch block is in some kind of loop ?